# Multiple 301 Redirect for many page to 1 page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with hundreds of products and many pages, I have redirected all pages with this rule

```
Redirect permanent /about-us/ http://www.domain.com/wedding-blog/about
```

But now I need to redirect my all products to another domain page, all product links, like this

```
/shopping/category.php?c=009591
```

is their any way redirect all my product under /shopping/ to another domain shopping page in a single redirect rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch 301 ^/shopping/(.*) http://example.com/shopping/
```

It will redirect anything in `/shopping/` to `example.com/shopping/`

EDIT:

```
RewriteRule ^shopping/(.*)$ http://example.com/shopping.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you I used this and work for me, only problem I found all redirected URL end with ?c=page_name, is their any way to remove this and show only clean redirected URL?

Comment: So you don't want `category.php?c=somenumber` to be on the new url?

Comment: Yes I dont want '?c=anything', I want just show new URL

Comment: Removing the `$1` from the url should do it then.

Comment: Sir, I already removed $1 and used RedirectMatch 301 ^/shopping/(.*) http://www.domain.com/shopping.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `mod_rewrite` rules to match query string and is it better to convert earlier rule to `mod_rewrite` as well:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about-us/?$ /wedding-blog/about [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=009591$
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /some-page? [NC,L,R=301]
```